# How to properly test a forwards any unmapped paths?

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am working on a project implemented in microservices on jhiptser and I am new to both topics. The gateway application runs in Angular. This application used HashLocationStrategy, but due to the need to integrate authentication through Linkedin, the location strategy has been changed to PathLocationStrategy. The reason is because the Linkedin app does not accept hash `#` in the required callback url. The problem that I now face is that after navigating to some route and then refreshing I receive a 404 with message on screen: Cannot GET /reset/

I have read about it and I understand I need to make a modification on the server side. Specifically the following:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class ClientForwardController {

    /**
     * Forwards any unmapped paths (except those containing a period) to the client {@code index.html}.
     * @return forward to client {@code index.html}.
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String forward() {
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

How can I test this in my development environment?

Right now I run the application running `npm run start` I reproduce what is described and when I refresh I get the message `Cannot GET /reset/request`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose you are running an old version of JHipster because HashLocationStrategy has been changed to PathLocationStrategy in 6.0 so I suppose also you copied current implementation and its test: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/main/src/test/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/web/rest/ClientForwardControllerTest.java  So what kind of tests do you want that is not covered by this one?

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is indeed an old version of jhipster. The script I have taken from this source https://github.com/ruddell/jhipster-examples/commit/2c31cf65eea96d45c8ed63845e2d96b04fb4b29f#diff-f814480d67d8634b804fcd809b34aee41d948d042b978e28a2f8b5ee3645c6b9

Comment: As mentioned I am new to this, I have collaborated in development on the angular side and executing `npm run start` is all I need but now the modifications are in java and I understand I should execute `./mvnw` but when doing so I get this error com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server, I would just appreciate a little guidance to know where to go

Comment: So you want to run your app and test interactively, so not with unit test I linked to. Your question lacks many details and with only a partial error, it's difficult to say. This error is usually raised by the gateway to notify you that either you did not start a microservice or you did not start the service registry. Ask your team mates.